# Pass Scala AST Tree directly to ScriptEngine

Tags: scala, scripting, abstract-syntax-tree

I have some ASTs that I am generating and then transforming via the toolbox parse method (i.e. from the `runtimeMirror`). Is there any way to pass the result of this into `ScriptEngine`?

```
val tb = runtimeMirror(this.getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
val tree = tb.parse(script)
val transformedTree = transform(tree)

// I'm keeping a script engine around during the session to use
val engine:ScriptEngine = globals.scriptEngine

// Is there a way to do this:
engine.eval(transformedTree)
```

Alternatively, is there a way to take the transformedTree and convert it back into Scala code? (So I can pass it to the script engine afterward)

Comment: Is `val res: ResTyp = tb.compile(transformedTree)().asInstanceOf[ResTyp]` not an option for some reason?

Comment: There are globals in the engine's context that are needed for the transformedTree to compile so just tb.compile(transformedTree) would return an error. Alternatively, is there a simple way to reuse results of previous compiles in the toolbox?

Comment: That is a good question, and I'm pretty sure that as long as your `transformedTree` contains only self-contained compilation units (like class or module definitions), the answer is "yes". I'm not so sure about whether you can get repl-like behavior with that (because `def`s and local `val`-definitions can't be compiled on their own). But that seems like another (related) question.

Comment: E.g.: `val tree = tb.parse("object A{def f=42}")` then modify `tree`, then `val a = tb.define(tree.asInstanceOf[ModuleDef])` and then use it `tb.eval(q"58 + $a.f")` gives `100`. So, in a way, you can create trees, then modify them, then add them as definition to `ToolBox`, then use them later. But it seems to work for classes and object definitions only. So: what's in your `transformedTree`? Class and module definitions, or something else?

Comment: It's possible that I can restrict it to Modules and Classes, but the trouble is, the stuff inside the eval i.e. `tb.eval(__thestuff__)` is not stuff that I control i.e. my client specifies that. Great idea though!